# Two separate 'if' statements in one Apex method

Tags: apex, conditional

I'm fairly new at Apex and have two fields that need to be set based on different criteria. I want both sets of If/Else to run, but based on looking at examples I am suspicious that maybe the second `if` might be hanging off the first one. Can I make sure both run somehow?

A related question -- I think I have learned that I can't just make them two methods and call them both in the action parameter of the actionSupport. Right?

Here's the code. Assume, please that all my fields are defined, etc. because I've checked that part a million times. :) There's a comment below showing where the two should be considered separate.

```
public pagereference MealFormatChange1() {
    if (dummyMeal.Form__c=='Sack' || dummyMeal.Form__c=='Cooler' || dummyMeal.Form__c=='Box') {
        dummyMeal.Meal_Location__c = DEFAULT_SACK_COOLER_LOCATION;
    } else  {dummyMeal.Meal_Location__c = DEFAULT_MEAL_LOCATION;}

    // Second, separate IF clause starts here
    if (dummyMeal.Type__c == 'Breakfast') {
        dummyMeal.Meal_Time__c = DEFAULT_BREAKFAST_TIME;
    } else if (dummyMeal.Type__c == 'Lunch') {
        if (dummyMeal.Form__c=='Sack' || dummyMeal.Form__c=='Cooler' || dummyMeal.Form__c=='Box') {
            dummyMeal.Meal_Time__c = DEFAULT_SACK_COOLER_LUNCH_TIME;
        } else { dummyMeal.Meal_Time__c = DEFAULT_LUNCH_TIME;}
    } else if (dummyMeal.Type__c == 'Dinner') {
        dummyMeal.Meal_Time__c = DEFAULT_DINNER_TIME;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're two separate sets of branch logic. You've written the code correctly.

If-then logic look like this:

```
if ( condition ) { expression-or-block } [ else { expression-or-block } ]
```

Your whitespace might be confusing you a bit, but you can definitely see that your first if statement follows the form perfectly.

For future reference, you should try to write your statements like this:

```
if(condition) { // This is on its own line
    do-when-true;
} else {  // This is also on its own line
    do-when-false;
}
```

And for chained if statements (as your second one is):

```
if(condition-1) {
    do-when-true-1;
} else if(condition-2) { // This should be its own line, too
    do-when-true-2;
} else {
    do-when-false;
}
```

Fixing your whitespace will help you determine how the logic flows.

As an aside, you'll notice that I said you can use an expression. That means it's legal to write:

```
if(condition)
    do-when-true;
else
    do-when-false;
```

But remember, you only get *one* statement, so this would be an error:

```
if(condition)
    do-when-true-1;
    do-when-true-2; // this will actually run regardless.
```

It's best to avoid doing that by explicitly using blocks (`{` through `}` is a block, and they can be contained inside each other).

Comment: Hmmm.  Well, thank you for the validation that I've written the code correctly.  In this case I am trying to use one If statement set to assign location and the other, completely separately, to assign time.  If I understand you right, that's what you think I've got there.   Now I'll have to figure out why the fields are not rerendering to display what I think I'm setting in that code.  (Yes, all those DEFAULT_ variables are set up at the top of the controller.)

Comment: @JeanneB Yeah, it might need some more code to figure out what's going on. Your if statements are okay. I'd recommend opening a new question with the code in question and a description of what behavior you're expecting vs what you're seeing.

Comment: I'll do that.  It could have something to do with rerendering, which seems to have so many gotcha!  Thanks, @sfdcfox

Comment: @JeanneB Rerendering is indeed often a tricky subject. You might try searching for a few questions here, maybe your problem's already been addressed before.

Comment: @sfcdfox even better, it was an eyeball thing.  Missing a pair of {} !  It works now.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @JeanneB You're welcome! I'm glad you got it fixed!